# Bash Getting each line of file to awk and have each column as a separate variable to run a command

Tags: linux, bash

Im trying to get this to take each line of a file that is formatted like `0310 05:00:00 AM` and use the 0310 to open ####_Dealer_schedule.txt and then grep the time followed by adding each result to an output file. I've attempted to redo it repeatedly but end up scrapping the result as its just not working.

**Code**:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "You have opened the Roulette Dealer Finder Program!"
echo "Do you have a list of dates and time? If so, run this script with the file as the arg"
echo "Make sure it is formatted as MMDD TIME"

#if the didnt give a file just ask them all the things
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
        echo "Enter Date as MMDD:"
        read date

        echo "Enter the Hour as ##:"
        read hour

        echo "Is this AM or PM?"
        echo "1) AM"
        echo "2) PM"
        read meridiem

        if [ "${meridiem}" = 1 ]; then
                echo "Here is the Roulette Dealer for" ${hour} "AM:"
                awk -F" " '{print $1,$2,$5,$6}' $date\_Dealer_schedule.txt | grep -i "${hour}:00:00 AM"

        elif [ "${meridiem}" = 2 ]; then
                echo "Here is the Roulette Dealer for" ${hour} "PM:"
                awk -F" " '{print $1,$2,$5,$6}' $date\_Dealer_schedule.txt | grep -i "${hour}:00:00 PM"
        else
                echo "You didnt pick from the available options..."
                echo "you selected: "${meridiem}
                echo "Please select either '1' or '2' next time."
        fi

# Now we want to do the thing for each of the lines in the file
else
        #slowly lose mind until it works or brain explodes
fi
```

**List File**:

```
0310 05:00:00 AM
0310 08:00:00 AM
0310 02:00:00 PM
0310 08:00:00 PM
0310 11:00:00 PM
0312 05:00:00 AM
0312 08:00:00 AM
0312 02:00:00 PM
0312 08:00:00 PM
0312 11:00:00 PM
0315 05:00:00 AM
0315 08:00:00 AM
0315 02:00:00 PM
```

## Here is a list of what I have tried:

**Testvar**:

```
        testvar=$(awk '{print $1}' $1 | uniq)

        head ${testvar}\_Dealer_schedule.txt
```

This output:

```
head: cannot open '0310' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open '0312' for reading: No such file or directory
==> 0315_Dealer_schedule.txt <==
Hour AM/PM  BlackJack_Dealer_FNAME LAST Roulette_Dealer_FNAME LAST  Texas_Hold_EM_dealer_FNAME LAST

12:00:00 AM Izabela Parrish Marlene Mcpherson   Madina Britton
01:00:00 AM Billy Jones Saima Mcdermott Summer-Louise Hammond
02:00:00 AM Summer-Louise Hammond   Abigale Rich    John-James Hayward
03:00:00 AM John-James Hayward  Evalyn Howell   Chyna Mercado
04:00:00 AM Chyna Mercado   Cleveland Hanna Katey Bean
05:00:00 AM Katey Bean  Billy Jones Evalyn Howell
06:00:00 AM Evalyn Howell   Saima Mcdermott Cleveland Hanna
07:00:00 AM Cleveland Hanna Abigale Rich    Billy Jones
```

**Xargs**:

```
        xargs < $1 -n 2 | awk -F" " '{print $1,$2}' > tempt.txt
        wc tempt.txt 
        awk -F" " '{print $1}' temp.txt
        #awk -F" " '{print $2}' temp.txt
```

this output:

```
 20  39 222 tempt.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open file `temp.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

**Array**:

```
        i=0
        while read line
        do 
          array[$((++i))]=$line
          echo ${array[$i]}
        done < $1
```

This output:

```
find_the_dealer.sh: 37: array[0]=0310: not found
find_the_dealer.sh: 38: Bad substitution
```

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: What is your intended purpose for using `-F" "` in your awk commands? Are you trying to set FS to a literal blank (which that does not do) instead of it's default any white space and, if so, what could be in your input to make that necessary?

Comment: `testvar` contains **all** the first fields, therefore you are running something like `head 0310 0312 0315_Dealer_schedule.txt`. I don't understand the logic in your program. Which of the first field values do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would you use `awk` for? Of course `awk` can open and handle additional files (other than its standard input), but this is somewhat easier to do in pure Bash. Here’s an ugly, inefficient hack, to show the basic principle:

```bash
while read -r prefix time meridiem discard; do
  grep -- "^${time} ${meridiem}" \
          "/path/to/${prefix}_Dealer_schedule.txt"
done < /path/to/list > /path/to/output
```

Now let’s make this↑ slightly more reasonable and efficient (fewer `grep` invocations, fewer file traversals):

```bash
declare -A prefix_times=()

while read -r prefix time meridiem discard; do
  prefix_times["$prefix"]+="|${time} ${meridiem}"
done < /path/to/list

for prefix in "${!prefix_times[@]}"; do
  grep -E -- "^(${prefix_times["$prefix"]:1})" \
             "/path/to/${prefix}_Dealer_schedule.txt"
done > /path/to/output
```